# Remote Desktop Client Disappearing from Taskbar after Loss of Connection

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I connect to several servers using Remote Desktop.  Some of my sessions will reconnect after a loss of connection.  Others will simply shut down and disappear from the taskbar.  The settings in my .rdp files are the same except for the host name.  How can I configure the connections so they always reconnect automatically (preferrably without a username/password prompt).

I'm sure the RDP settings are identical

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the settings are identical?  This is found, for a given RDP, by clicking Options, then on the Experience tab, select the "Reconnect if connection is dropped" check-box.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the RDP settings are identical.